# convert Object into Object[]

Tags: java

the method inside the library I'm using return an object but it's really is an array of objects. And I'm stuck where I need that value. It's weird that no one has asked for a conversion like this.

Comment: That's because it makes no sense.

Comment: Yup, I've read the question multiple times now, and either come up with different readings of it or just been confused.

Comment: not without context, anyway...

Comment: Is this a question about simple cast? If so, it's almost at level of read-the-friendly-dummies-4-java-book... :-/

Comment: @Ignacio: It makes sense. An array is a valid Object. Whether an object is array can be checked with Object.isArray().

Comment: @Joonas, [`Object`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html) does **not** have an isArray method.

Comment: @Matthew Flaschen Good call -- however, [Class](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html) does, assuming the source is non-null: `theObj.getClass().isArray()` -- I'd just as soon try the cast and die horribly if something is amiss :-)

Comment: @pst, or just use `instanceof Object[]`, which I would guess is faster than two method calls.

Comment: instanceof has the additional benefit that it also checks for null. If theObj would be null, surely theObj.getClass() will throw a NPE.

Comment: @Matthew Flaschen: Yes, I forgot to get the class. The whole thing would be `null != object ? object.getClass().isArray() : false`. The difference between this and `instanceof Object[]` is that the former returns `true` for an array of any element type, and the latter requires the element type to be strictly `Object`. Which one is needed depends on the use case.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
    Object[] objects = new Object[] {1,"fde", 5L};
    Object cast = objects;
    Object[] recovered = (Object[]) cast;
```

Answer (score 3):

```
Object o = ...
Object[] array = { o };
```

Comment: Hmmm... I thought it was the other way around.

Comment: @Khoi, could you be a little more specific about this *not working*?

Comment: @Rekin, when I read the title I was lead to believe that he was trying to convert an `object into object[]` but you are correct that this contradicts with the question body.

Comment: The elements of 'array' doesnt reference to the element of original array. The answer of Rekin work though. So this mean there is array object and array primitive? Dumb me :P

Answer (score 3):

Many APIs return Object, because that's the most general thing to return. This is typically the case for general containers in which you can store many different types. A getter style method is then unable to return anything more specific.

There should be no need for any explicit 'conversion'. Just cast it and you're done.

```
Object object = MyApi.getFoo();
Object[] theRealThing = (Object[]) object;
```

Or if you want to be sure that the cast is going to work:

```
Object object = MyApi.getFoo();
if (object instanceof Object[]) {
    Object[] theRealThing = (Object[]) object;
} else {
    System.out.println("The impossible has happened!"); // or something like that
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simplay cast it like this:

```
Object[] arrayOfObjects = (Object[]) yourMethod();
```